# Removing only particular type of overlays in objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have overlays of `MKcircle`, `MKpolygon` on `mapView`. when I increase size of circle using slider, I have to do

```
[self.mapView removeOverlays:[self.mapView overlays]];
```

and because of this above line my `MKpolygon` also removes. I don't want to remove my polygon. I am not getting how to do this. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below for In loop for not removing `MKPolygon`.

```
for (id overLay in [self.mapView overlays]) {
        if (![overLay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]]) {
            [self.mapView removeOverlay:overLay];
        }
    }
```

It will helps you.